# TimelineJS App - How to Set the Height of the Content Area?

Tags: 2sxc, timeline.js

I've got the app working and all my entries entered. A few are causing a scroll bar to appear. I have reviewed the Timeline.js project docs and setting the height of the content area seems easy enough. However, after digging in on the 2sxc app wrapper, I am unable to find the right way to get that setting/option passed in to the timeline-embed object. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question. Hopefully someone in the future benefits from this...

Very simple answer is to edit the height in the /TimelineJS/assets/styles.css

We missed this previously simply because it wasn't working - until we turned off CRM/Enable Composite Files and cleared cache, etc.